# Ionic React send Object Prop to Child Component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic-react

I just dont get it. I am kinda new to Typescript but used to Code in React.js.
I have a simple Component like

```
const Tab1: React.FC = () => {

  const [spices, setSpices] = useState(
    [
      {
        Gewuerz: "pepper",
        Gramm: 50,
      },
      {
        Gewuerz: "Tumeric",
        Gramm: 870,
      },
      {
        Gewuerz: "salt",
        Gramm: 40,
      },
      {
        Gewuerz: "muscat",
        Gramm: 9,
      }
    ]);

  return (
    <IonPage>
      <IonHeader>
        <IonToolbar>
          <IonTitle class="ion-text-center">Spices</IonTitle>
        </IonToolbar>
      </IonHeader>
      <IonContent>
        <SpiceList spices={spices}/>
      </IonContent>
      

    </IonPage>

    
  );
};
```

And a Child Component like

```
interface Props {
   spices: Object[];
 }




const SpiceList: React.FC<Props> = ({spices}: Props) => {

  return (

      <IonContent>
        <IonList>
          {spices.map((e) => <IonItem>{e.Gewuerz}</IonItem>)}
        </IonList>
      </IonContent>
   
    
  )
      
};

export default SpiceList;
```

I want to render the different Spices inside Prop as a List. I can Map the Prop spices. But i cant access `e.Gewuerz` as it says it is not available inside of `e`. So how can i access the SubElements of spices?

EDIT: So it actually works like i tried it. But it always says "Compiled with Errors." If i dismiss it the app renders like i want it to.

Answer (score 1):

A vague type like `object` doesn't have any known properties, so Typescript won't let you access any properties on it.

Your spices are all of a specific type `{ Gewuerz: string; Gramm: number; }` so you need to use that type in order to get any useful type information.

You can use that type as-is:

```
interface Props {
  spices: { Gewuerz: string; Gramm: number; }[];
}
```

But you probably want to create a named type alias.  Especially if this `Spice` object is something that you use throughout your app.

```
interface Spice {
  Gewuerz: string;
  Gramm: number;
}

interface Props {
  spices: Spice[];
}
```

Note that you do not need to use `React.FC<Props>` **and** `({spices}: Props)`.  You only need one or the other.